# Put grep output inside variable from a loop

Tags: linux, bash

I have CentOS and this bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
files=$( ls /vps_backups/site )
counter=0
for i in $files ; do
echo $i | grep -o -P '(?<=-).*(?=.tar)'
let counter=$counter+1
done
```

In the site folder I have compressed backups with the following names :

```
    site-081916.tar.gz
    site-082016.tar.gz
    site-082116.tar.gz
    ...
```

The code above prints :
081916
082016
082116

I want to put each extracted date to a variable so I replaced this line

```
echo $i | grep -o -P '(?<=-).*(?=.tar)'
```

with this :

```
dt=$($i | grep -o -P '(?<=-).*(?=.tar)')
echo $dt
```

however I get this error :

```
./test.sh: line 6: site-090316.tar.gz: command not found
```

Any help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you still need the `echo` inside the `$(...)`:

```
dt=$(echo $i | grep -o -P '(?<=-).*(?=.tar)')
```

Comment: Well, that's a fast and perfect answer for my issue, I'm new to bash, thank you.

Comment: for what it's worth: you can make this more efficient by moving the `grep` into the `$files` definition:  `files=$( ls /vps_backups/site | grep -o -P '(?<=-).*(?=.tar)' )` - that way, `files` will be just the filename parts you're looking for already.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ls` in a script. Use a shell pattern instead. Also, you don't need to use `grep`; `bash` has a built-in regular expression operator.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$( /vps_backups/site/* )
counter=0
for i in "${files[@]#/vps_backups/site/}" ; do
  [[ $i =~ -(.*).tar.gz ]] && dt=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```